# Cannot Upload to Imgur PHP

Tags: php, image, imgur

This Code normally works, But recently it has not been working and I don't know why... I never touch it, but I suspect that ever since I reinstalled google Chrome It has had some sort of effect. 
Here is the error,

file_get_contents([http://api.imgur.com/3/image](https://api.imgur.com/3/image)): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\administrator\index.php on line 92

```html
if (isset($_POST['change1'])) {

 $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']));

$options = array('http'=>array(
'method'=>"POST",               
'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer 5ac2b1b64fdfea5e062d5c477a49c68b69993213\n".
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
'content'=>$image
));

$imgurURL = "http://api.imgur.com/3/image";


$context = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($imgurURL, false, $context);

$response = json_decode($response);



DB::query("UPDATE products SET image1=:image1 WHERE id=:id",array(':image1'=>$response->data->link,':id'=>$_GET['edit']));

 
}
```

Comment: what does your PHP error log tell you?

Comment: You've just posted your access token to the Internet. You should expire it immediately.

Comment: What specifically isn't working?  This is far too vague to answer as it currently stands

Comment: Hello Everyone, This is what it is saying:      file_get_contents(http://api.imgur.com/3/image): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

Comment: @DércioLichucha Click "edit" and modify your question with relevant information. Thanks